# The set of algebraic numbers is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I need help proving  this stunning result.

Let me state it this way.

Let  $\mathbb L$ be a field and $\mathbb K$ be a field with $\mathbb K \subset \mathbb L$

Let $A$ be the set of algebraic numbers ie $A=\{a \in \mathbb L, \exists P \in \mathbb K [X], P(a)=0 \}$

I managed to prove that $A$ is a ring with the following reasoning:

If $a,b \in A$ then $ \mathbb K[a]$ is a ring.

And $ \mathbb K \subset \mathbb K[a] \subset \mathbb K[a][b] $

Some finite-dimension argument(ask details if needed) proves that $\mathbb K[a][b]$ has finite dimension as a vector space over the field $\mathbb K$

Reminding that $\mathbb K[a+b] \subset \mathbb K[a][b]$ and $\mathbb K[ab] \subset \mathbb K[a][b]$ proves that they both have finite dimension, hence $a$ and $b$ algebraic.

How should I proceed with inverses ?

Comment: I might be lost here, but it sounds like you already prove that $A$ is a field...I meant, all the operation are inherited from the big field $L$ so the only thing you need to check is closure.

Comment: @Gina, I believe that is what he is checking, not the existence of $a^{-1}$, but a proof that $a^{-1}$ is algebraic.

Comment: Huh? But isn't $K[a]=K[a^{-1}]$ so both of them are finite extension?

Comment: If $p(x)=0$ and $q(y)=0$ where $p$ and $q$ are known polynomial functions, how does one find a polynomial of which $x+y$ is a root?  From proofs of this kind, one can actually construct such a polynomial.  I did it once.  I've forgotten the details.

Comment: @MichaelHardy:I believe you can find it in a standard proof of algebraic INTEGER. I struggled for days on that in Herstein and end up have to look up the details. For just algebraic number the finite dimension argument is good enough though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $r\ne 0$ be a root of the equation $a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_n=0$. Then $\frac{1}{r}$ is a root of the equation $a_nx^n +a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_1x+a_0=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

For any $\;0\neq a\in A\;$ :

$$a\in\Bbb K[a]=\Bbb K(a)\implies a^{-1}\in \Bbb K(a)\le A\ldots$$

Comment: Hmm I don't know much about $\mathbb K(a)$. Is it the field of fractions ?

Comment: Yes, of the ring $\;\Bbb K[a]\;$ , but this is one of the first things that are *usually* studied in fields theory: if $\;L/K\;$ is a fields extension, then an element $\;a\in L\;$ is algebraic over $\;K\;$ iff $\;K[a]=K(a)\;$ . A simple, **very important**, characterization of algebraic elements.