# Constructing an infinite chain of subfields of 'hyper' algebraic numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory, transcendental-numbers

This has now been [cross posted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319167/constructing-an-infinite-chain-of-subsets-of-hyper-algebraic-numbers) to MO.

Let $F$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $S_F$ denote the set of values which satisfy some generalized polynomial whose exponents and coefficients are drawn from $F$. 
That is, we let $S_F$ denote
$$\bigg \{x \in \mathbb{R}: 0=\sum_{i=1}^n{a_i x^{e_i}}: e_i \in F \text{ distinct}, a_i\in F \text{ non-zero}, n\in \mathbb{N}  \bigg  \}$$

Then $S_{\mathbb{\mathbb{Q}}}$ is the set of algebraic real numbers and we start to see the beginnings of a chain:

$
\mathbb{Q}
\subsetneq S_\mathbb{Q} \subsetneq
S_{S_\mathbb{Q}} $

**Main Question**

> Does this chain continue forever? That is, we let $A_0= \mathbb{Q}$ and let $A_{n+1}=S_{A_{n}}$. Is it the case that $A_n \subsetneq A_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

**Other curiosities:**

Is $A_i$ always a field? Perhaps, the argument is analogous to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331017/enlightening-proof-that-the-algebraic-numbers-form-a-field). Or maybe this is just the case in a more general setting: Is it the case that $F \subset \mathbb{R}$, a field implies that $S_F$ is a field?

Is it possible to see that $e\notin \cup A_i$? Perhaps this is just a tweaking of [LW Theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)

Comment: Every set in the chain is countable, so you certainly don't hit $\mathbb{R}$ at any point.

Comment: How do you propose to define $x^\alpha$ if $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: $2^{\sqrt2}$ is transcendental, but it satisfies $x^{\sqrt2}-4=0$, so it's in $A_2$. I'd conjecture that $2^{2^{\sqrt2}}$ is in $A_3$ and not $A_2$, that $2^{2^{2^{\sqrt2}}}$ is in $A_4$ and not $A_3$, etcetera.

Comment: I'm still somewhat concerned about the definition of $x^\alpha$ when $x<0$ and $\alpha$ is not an integer. But, there is a cool question  in here (possibly a very difficult one).

Comment: Mason, I had some simple worries in my mind. Like is $S_F$ necessarily closed under negation?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen.  Just to be clear about the concern raised: $ x^{\sqrt2}-2=0 \implies x= \sqrt{2}^{1/\sqrt{2}}$ What (generalized) polynomial is satisfied by $-x$? It could be that $ (-x)^{\sqrt2}-2=0$ is not a satisfactory answer. No. I would think this is indeed a satisfactory answer. The first polynomial has a non negative domain and the second has a non positive domain. What trouble do we get into if we take this naive approach? This route at least wins us closure under negation. Oh. The trouble we get into is when someone asks what the coefficient of the $x^{\sqrt 2}$ term is...

Comment: (continued) We should answer $e^{i \pi \sqrt{2}}$ but all of sudden it's start look like the question is better raised in the complex numbers. But maybe there is a different polynomial that satisfies $-x$?

Comment: Just a question: is $n$ (defined inside the definition of $S_F$ as a natural number) also arbitrary for any member of $S_F$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, for this purpose I think we can define $(-|x|)^\alpha$ as $-(|x|^\alpha)$.

Comment: I don’t think we can rule out $e\in A_3$. My impression is that we know almost nothing about the transcendence of numbers like $3^\sqrt6-4^\sqrt3-1$.

Comment: How do we prove that $4^\sqrt3+1\in\cup A_n$? This seems like an argument for defining $S_F$ to include closure under field operations.

Comment: It seems like we might be able to achieve multiplicative inverses using a technique analogous to the one presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626432/the-set-of-algebraic-numbers-is-a-field#626446). I haven't worked out all the details but it looks like it could be a [good lead](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xl1gro6akh)

Comment: Actually... $S_F$ is clearly closed under multiplicative inverses because $-e_i$ is in a field $F$ whenever $e_i$ is in $F$

Comment: I am not so sure but maybe this [piece](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0168007204001058/1-s2.0-S0168007204001058-main.pdf?_tid=76e72f5e-ece2-4dfc-a368-f0c4a88d2717&acdnat=1545408642_f668fd4519d826dbc4b13f9b69df6549) by B Zilbner speaks to the question.

Comment: Why is $S_\mathbb Q$ equal to the set of algebraic real numbers? For instance, is any solution to $\sqrt x+\sqrt[3]x=0$ algebraic?

Comment: @JackM, $x=0$ satisfies this and is algebraic. I am not sure I understand your meaning... 
But if you take $x=y^6$ then we can replace your equation with $y^3+y^2=0$ and we can always manage to do this type of change when the exponents are rational.